How to send text, image to WhatsApp to the specified number
How to send the image text  the specific WhatsApp number.                        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image")); https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=918072008466 I want to go to this whatsapp number. I tried many times but I can't get to the specific whatsapp number.
String share_title = android.text.Html.fromHtml(post.recipe_title).toString();
                    String share_price = android.text.Html.fromHtml("price:"+ post.discountprice).toString();
                    String share_Address = android.text.Html.fromHtml("Address:"+ user.Address).toString();
                    String share_pincode = android.text.Html.fromHtml("PinCode:"+user.PinCode).toString();
                    String share_Distict = android.text.Html.fromHtml("State:"+user.State).toString();
                    String titile= share_title + "\n\n"+ share_price + "\n\n" +share_Address +"\n\n"+ share_pincode + "\n\n"+ share_Distict + "\n\n" ;

                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("image/*");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));

                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titile);

                    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

How to send the image, text the specific WhatsApp number

try this :
String share_title = android.text.Html.fromHtml(post.recipe_title).toString();
String share_price = android.text.Html.fromHtml("price:" + post.discountprice).toString();
String share_Address = android.text.Html.fromHtml("Address:" + user.Address).toString();
String share_pincode = android.text.Html.fromHtml("PinCode:" + user.PinCode).toString();
String share_Distict = android.text.Html.fromHtml("State:" + user.State).toString();
String title = share_title + "\n\n" + share_price + "\n\n" + share_Address + "\n\n" + share_pincode + "\n\n" + share_Distict + "\n\n";

String phoneNumber = "918072008466"; // The specific WhatsApp number

// Create a WhatsApp URL with the text to be sent
String whatsappUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumber + "&text=" + Uri.encode(title);

// Create an intent to send the image
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));

// Add text separately to ensure both image and text are sent
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);

// Ensure the image is sent to the specific WhatsApp number
share.setData(Uri.parse(whatsappUrl));

// Set the package to WhatsApp
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

try {
    // Start the intent
    this.startActivity(share);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // WhatsApp not installed, handle the exception
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Key Points:
Text Message Construction: Constructs the text message from the provided fields.
WhatsApp URL: Creates a URL with the phone number and encoded text.
Intent Setup: Sets up an intent to share the image and text.
Package Specification: Ensures WhatsApp handles the intent.
Exception Handling: Catches the ActivityNotFoundException in case WhatsApp is not installed.

error bro https://ibb.co/p2wxGjN

direct wattsapp number not send bro

How to send direct wattsapp number image text
